# Find a place using coordinates in google maps: differences between Google Maps web application ad Google Maps API v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I need to locate a point on a Google Maps using Google Maps API v3.

This is a sample: 42.62649134593722, 13.283811807632446

If I use Google Maps https://www.google.it/maps/place/42%C2%B037'35.4%22N+13%C2%B017'01.7%22E/@42.6264913,13.2816231,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d42.6264913!4d13.2838118 web application I obtain this

[image]

Using the Geocoding example ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) on the same coordinates couple I've seen that the marker on the map is located in a different location

[image]

How may I have the same behaviour and location using Geocoding API? Alternatives? Examples?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `42.62649134593722, 13.283811807632446` is a latitude and longitude value. It is an exact point on the map.

In the second screenshot you are attempting to geocode the value of `42.62649134593722, 13.283811807632446`, despite it being an exact location already.

Geocoding is:

> Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600
>   Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates
>   (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use
>   to place markers on a map or position the map.
>   - Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

If you already have the lat/lng I am unsure why you would need to utilise the geocoding API...

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/2763/

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle but my problem it's not how to put a point on the map when I know the coordinates couple, but how to use a text input where my user can to write and address, a place name or, also, a coordinates couple and to show the point on the map exactly as Google Maps application does ..... what Google API I've to use to obtain the same  behaviour that I've when use the Google Map web application?

Comment: Like the post says geocoding is turning addresses into a geographic lat lng. Say the lat long is in a field, you are never going to get that location via the use of geolocating, that is not the purpose of the service. The easiest solution would be a radio button for geolocation or exact lat/lng values